# How to invoke void function in Object Literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, frontend

When the function has return value it works, if it is void it doesn't. How do I invoke void function like this when it is object's value?

Code with if-else statements:

```
const handlePageChange = (number, type) => {

      const handlePage = () => setCurrentPage(number)
      const handleAllLeft = () => setCurrentPage(1)
      const handleAllRight = () => setCurrentPage(Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage))
      const handleLeft = () => {
        if(currentPage === 1) setCurrentPage(1)
        else setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
      }
      const handleRight = () => {
        if(currentPage === Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage)) setCurrentPage(Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage))
        else setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
      }
      
      if(type === "page") handlePage()
      if(type === "all-left") handleAllLeft()
      if(type === "all-right") handleAllRight()
      if(type === "left") handleLeft()
      if(type === "right") handleRight()
    }
```

Code with object literals:

```
const renderPagination = () => {
    const pageNumbers = []

    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i)
    }


    const handlePageChange = (number, type) => {

      const handlePage = () => setCurrentPage(number)
      const handleAllLeft = () => setCurrentPage(1)
      const handleAllRight = () => setCurrentPage(Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage))
      const handleLeft = () => {
        if(currentPage === 1) setCurrentPage(1)
        else setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
      }
      const handleRight = () => {
        if(currentPage === Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage)) setCurrentPage(Math.ceil(data?.length / dataPerPage))
        else setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
      }


      const obj = {
        "page": handlePage(),
        "all-left": handleAllLeft(),
        "all-right": handleAllRight(),
        "left": handleLeft(),
        "right": handleRight()
      }

      return obj[type] || null
    }
```

Tried returning null after state update, still no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difference with your approaches is that the second one executes all the functions when you assign the object values

```
 const obj = {
        "page": handlePage(),
        "all-left": handleAllLeft(),
        "all-right": handleAllRight(),
        "left": handleLeft(),
        "right": handleRight()
      }
```

If you want the same executions as in the first code, you can assign the functions, then execute the one you want on the return

```
   const obj = {
        "page": handlePage,
        "all-left": handleAllLeft,
        "all-right": handleAllRight,
        "left": handleLeft,
        "right": handleRight
      }

    return obj[type]() || null // <-- See extra parenthesis here
```

Comment: Yes, but this `obj[type]() || null` could still lead to other issues like `obj[xy] is not a function` and the `|| null` is then useless. Perhaps you might want to use: `obj[type]?.() || null` instead - then suddenly you have a desired `null` output instead of a crashed application.

Comment: I agree @RokoC.Buljan, your suggestions are sound. Theres a lot of issues with structuring the code this way, and little benefit - i would advise agains it altogether